# When using conda-build, got 'conda.exceptions.UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have successfully built and uploaded my own Python package on PyPI and tried to upload the package to Anaconda cloud as well. However, when following the documentation of **Conda**'s [build package with skeleton](https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html#), and using `conda-build` command, I got an error:

```
conda.exceptions.UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
...
```

OS: win10
conda: v4.8.5

Steps to reproduce this problem:

**1. **Create a new Conda environment with following package installed.****

```
conda create -n easygraph python=3.6.8
conda activate easygraph
conda install --file requirements.txt
```

the `requirments.txt`:

```
numpy>=1.18.5
tqdm>=4.49.0
tensorflow>=2.0.0
joblib>=0.16.0
six>=1.15.0
gensim>=3.8.3
progressbar33>=2.4
scikit-learn>=0.23.2
scipy>=1.5.2
```

**2. Open a new folder and run powershell here with:**

```
conda activate easygraph
conda skeleton pypi Python-EasyGraph
```

This will generate a `meta.yaml` file:

```
{% set name = "Python-EasyGraph" %}
{% set version = "0.2a12" %}

package:
  name: "{{ name|lower }}"
  version: "{{ version }}"

source:
  url: "https://pypi.io/packages/source/{{ name[0] }}/{{ name }}/{{ name }}-{{ version }}.tar.gz"
  sha256: 2086d027fb46a2e873467c2278dca2cc22e6d16096a5cf5d1526616e06a30db4

build:
  number: 0
  script: "{{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . -vv"

requirements:
  host:
    - python
    - numpy 1.18.5
    - gensim >=3.8.3
    - joblib >=0.16.0
    - pip
    - progressbar33 >=2.4
    - scikit-learn >=0.23.2
    - scipy >=1.5.2
    - six >=1.15.0
    - tensorflow >=2.0.0
    - tqdm >=4.49.0
  run:
    - python
    - numpy 1.18.5
    - gensim >=3.8.3
    - joblib >=0.16.0
    - progressbar33 >=2.4
    - scikit-learn >=0.23.2
    - scipy >=1.5.2
    - six >=1.15.0
    - tensorflow >=2.0.0
    - tqdm >=4.49.0

test:
  imports:
    - easygraph
    - easygraph.classes
    - easygraph.datasets
    - easygraph.functions
    - easygraph.functions.centrality
    - easygraph.functions.community
    - easygraph.functions.components
    - easygraph.functions.drawing
    - easygraph.functions.graph_embedding
    - easygraph.functions.not_sorted
    - easygraph.functions.path
    - easygraph.functions.structural_holes
    - easygraph.utils

about:
  home: "https://github.com/easy-graph/Easy-Graph"
  license: BSD
  license_family: BSD
  license_file: 
  summary: "Easy Graph"
  doc_url: 
  dev_url: 

extra:
  recipe-maintainers:
    - your-github-id-here
```

3. Then run `conda-build`:

```
conda-build Python-EasyGraph
```

after which I met an error:

```
(easygraph) PS C:\Users\A\Desktop\conda_trial> conda-build Python-EasyGraph                                             No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.11
WARNING:conda_build.metadata:No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.11
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Attempting to finalize metadata for python-easygraph
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for python-easygraph
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... WARNING:conda.models.version:Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(537): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1
WARNING:conda.models.version:Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 2.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 2
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(537): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 2.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 2
WARNING:conda.models.version:Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 3.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 3
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(537): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 3.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 3
WARNING:conda.models.version:Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 2.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 2
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(537): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 2.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 2
WARNING:conda.models.version:Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 4.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 4
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(537): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 4.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 4
WARNING:conda.models.version:Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 3.6.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 3.6
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(537): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 3.6.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 3.6
WARNING:conda.models.version:Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 0.23.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 0.23
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(537): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 0.23.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 0.23

Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining pip:   8%|█████▋                                                              | 1/12 [00:00<00:02,  4.06Examining pip:  17%|███████████▎                                                        | 2/12 [00:00<00:01,Examining joblib[version='>=0.16.0']:  17%|███████▌                                     | 2/12 [00:04<00:01,  8.Examining joblib[version='>=0.16.0']:  25%|███████████▎                                 | 3/12 [00:04<00:12,Examining progressbar33[version='>=2.4']:  25%|██████████▎                              | 3/12 [00:04<00:12, Examining progressbar33[version='>=2.4']:  33%|█████████████▋                           | 4/12 [00:04<00:0Examining tensorflow[version='>=2.0.0']:  33%|██████████████                            | 4/12 [00:04<00:0Examining six[version='>=1.15.0']:  42%|████████████████████                            | 5/12 [00:0Examining scipy[version='>=1.5.2']:  50%|███████████████████████▌                       | 6/12 [Examining gensim[version='>=3.8.3']:  58%|██████████████████████████▊                   | 7/1Examining gensim[version='>=3.8.3']:  67%|██████████████████████████████▋               |Examining @/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0:  67%|███████████████████████████████▎               Examining scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2']:  75%|█████████████████████████████▎         | Examining numpy=1.18.5:  83%|█████████████████████████████████████████████ Examining numpy=1.18.5:  92%|█████████████████████████████████████████████ Examining tqdm[version='>=4.49.0']:  92%|███████████████████████████████████████ Examining conflict for python gensim tensorflow pip:   8%|██▌                           | 1/12 [00:00<00:02,  4.33it/Examining conflict for python gensim tensorflow pip:  17%|█████                         | 2/12 [00:00<00:01,  8.66iExamining conflict for python tensorflow pip:  17%|██████▏                              | 2/12 [00:00<00:01,  8.6Examining conflict for python tensorflow:  25%|██████████▎                              | 3/12 [00:00<00:01, Examining conflict for python tensorflow:  33%|█████████████▋                           | 4/12 [00:00<00:0Examining conflict for python pip progressbar33 six tqdm:  33%|████████▎                | 4/12 [00:00<00:00,  9Examining conflict for python pip:  42%|████████████████████                            | 5/12 [00:0Examining conflict for python pip joblib tensorflow scikit-learn:  50%|████████▌        | 6/12 [00:00<00:00,  9Examining conflict for python pip joblib tensorflow scikit-learn:  58%|█████████▉       | 7/12 [00:00<00:00, 1Examining conflict for pip tensorflow six scipy gensim numpy:  58%|████████████▎        | 7/12 [00:00<00:00Examining conflict for tqdm progressbar33 six pip:  67%|█████████████████████▎          | 8/12 [00Examining conflict for tqdm progressbar33 six pip:  75%|████████████████████████        | 9/12 [Examining conflict for pip joblib scipy gensim scikit-learn numpy:  75%|████████████    | 9/12 [00:00<00:00,Examining conflict for joblib pip:  83%|███████████████████████████████████████▏Examining conflict for joblib pip:  92%|████████████████████████████████████████Examining conflict for pip joblib progressbar33 six tqdm:  92%|██████████████████████  | 11/12 [00Examining conflict for joblib scikit-learn: 100%|███████████████████████████████████ failed

Leaving build/test directories:
  Work:
 D:\anaconda3\conda-bld\work
  Test:
 D:\anaconda3\conda-bld\test_tmp
Leaving build/test environments:
  Test:
source activate  D:\anaconda3\conda-bld\_test_env
  Build:
source activate  D:\anaconda3\conda-bld\_build_env


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\environ.py", line 787, in get_install_actions
    actions = install_actions(prefix, index, specs, force=True)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plan.py", line 474, in install_actions
    txn = solver.solve_for_transaction(prune=prune, ignore_pinned=not pinned)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
    unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 281, in solve_final_state
    ssc = self._run_sat(ssc)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 815, in _run_sat
    ssc.solution_precs = ssc.r.solve(tuple(final_environment_specs),
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 1321, in solve
    self.find_conflicts(specs, specs_to_add, history_specs)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 352, in find_conflicts
    raise UnsatisfiableError(bad_deps, strict=strict_channel_priority)
conda.exceptions.UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package requests conflicts for:
pip -> requests
python=3.8 -> pip -> requests
tensorflow[version='>=2.0.0'] -> tensorboard[version='>=2.1.0'] -> requests[version='>=2.21.0,<3']
gensim[version='>=3.8.3'] -> smart_open[version='>=1.2.1'] -> requests

Package tzdata conflicts for:
pip -> python[version='>=3'] -> tzdata
joblib[version='>=0.16.0'] -> python[version='>=3.6'] -> tzdata
six[version='>=1.15.0'] -> python -> tzdata
progressbar33[version='>=2.4'] -> python -> tzdata
tqdm[version='>=4.49.0'] -> python -> tzdata

Package numpy-base conflicts for:
numpy=1.18.5 -> numpy-base=1.18.5
gensim[version='>=3.8.3'] -> numpy[version='>=1.18.4,<2.0a0'] -> numpy-base[version='1.18.1.*|1.18.5.*|1.19.1',build='py38ha3acd2a_0|py36ha3acd2a_0|py37ha3acd2a_0']
numpy=1.18.5 -> mkl_fft -> numpy-base[version='>=1.0.14,<2.0a0|>=1.0.6,<2.0a0|>=1.0.2,<2.0a0|>=1.0.4,<2.0a0']
scipy[version='>=1.5.2'] -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> numpy-base[version='1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.17.2.*|1.17.3.*|1.17.4.*|1.18.1.*|1.18.5.*|1.19.1|1.17.0|1.17.0',build='py37hc3f5095_0|py36h8128ebf_4|py27h2753ae9_4|py37hc3f5095_5|py36h4a99626_0|py27hfef472a_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py35h8128ebf_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_1|py27hb1d0314_1|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py38ha3acd2a_0|py36ha3acd2a_0|py37ha3acd2a_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py38hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py37hc3f5095_1|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py27hb1d0314_1|py36hc3f5095_1|py37hc3f5095_1|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_1|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py35h8128ebf_0|py37h4a99626_0|py35h4a99626_0|py36hc3f5095_5|py27hb1d0314_5|py38hc3f5095_4|py35h8128ebf_4|py37h8128ebf_4|py36hc3f5095_0']
scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2'] -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> numpy-base[version='1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.17.2.*|1.17.3.*|1.17.4.*|1.18.1.*|1.18.5.*|1.19.1|1.17.0|1.17.0',build='py37hc3f5095_0|py36h8128ebf_4|py27h2753ae9_4|py37hc3f5095_5|py36h4a99626_0|py27hfef472a_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py35h8128ebf_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_1|py27hb1d0314_1|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py38ha3acd2a_0|py36ha3acd2a_0|py37ha3acd2a_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py38hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py37hc3f5095_1|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py27hb1d0314_1|py36hc3f5095_1|py37hc3f5095_1|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_1|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py35h8128ebf_0|py37h4a99626_0|py35h4a99626_0|py36hc3f5095_5|py27hb1d0314_5|py38hc3f5095_4|py35h8128ebf_4|py37h8128ebf_4|py36hc3f5095_0']

Package certifi conflicts for:
pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26|>=2017.4.17']
joblib[version='>=0.16.0'] -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']

Package python conflicts for:
pip -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3|3.4.*']
six[version='>=1.15.0'] -> python
tensorflow[version='>=2.0.0'] -> tensorboard[version='>=2.1.0'] -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5|>=3.2|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']
joblib[version='>=0.16.0'] -> setuptools -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|3.4.*']
joblib[version='>=0.16.0'] -> python[version='>=3.6']
gensim[version='>=3.8.3'] -> numpy[version='>=1.18.4,<2.0a0'] -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.4.*|>=3.5|3.7.*|3.8.*']
progressbar33[version='>=2.4'] -> python
scipy[version='>=1.5.2'] -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0'] -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2'] -> joblib[version='>=0.11'] -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.5|3.8.*|3.7.*']
tensorflow[version='>=2.0.0'] -> python[version='3.6.*|3.7.*']
numpy=1.18.5 -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0'] -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.8.*|3.7.*']
numpy=1.18.5 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']
scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2'] -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']
tqdm[version='>=4.49.0'] -> python
scipy[version='>=1.5.2'] -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']
pip -> setuptools -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
gensim[version='>=3.8.3'] -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']

Package setuptools conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> pip -> setuptools
pip -> setuptools
tensorflow[version='>=2.0.0'] -> tensorboard[version='>=2.1.0'] -> setuptools[version='>=41.0.0|>=41.4']
joblib[version='>=0.16.0'] -> setuptools
scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2'] -> joblib[version='>=0.11'] -> setuptools

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
progressbar33[version='>=2.4'] -> python -> ca-certificates
tqdm[version='>=4.49.0'] -> python -> ca-certificates
pip -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
six[version='>=1.15.0'] -> python -> ca-certificates
python=3.8 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates

Package numpy conflicts for:
gensim[version='>=3.8.3'] -> numpy[version='>=1.18.1,<2.0a0|>=1.18.4,<2.0a0']
scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2'] -> scipy -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.15.1,<2.0a0']
gensim[version='>=3.8.3'] -> scipy[version='>=0.18.1'] -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.15.1,<2.0a0']
numpy=1.18.5
tensorflow[version='>=2.0.0'] -> tensorboard[version='>=2.1.0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.12.0|>=1.16|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.16.1']
scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2'] -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0']
scipy[version='>=1.5.2'] -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0']
scipy[version='>=1.5.2'] -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0']

Package openblas conflicts for:
scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2'] -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> openblas[version='>=0.2.20,<0.2.21.0a0|>=0.3.3,<0.3.4.0a0']
numpy=1.18.5 -> libblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0'] -> openblas[version='0.3.5.*|0.3.6|>=0.3.6,<0.3.7.0a0',build=h828a276_2]
scipy[version='>=1.5.2'] -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> openblas[version='>=0.2.20,<0.2.21.0a0|>=0.3.3,<0.3.4.0a0']

Package m2w64-gcc-libs conflicts for:
numpy=1.18.5 -> libblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0'] -> m2w64-gcc-libs
scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2'] -> libcblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0'] -> m2w64-gcc-libs

Package webencodings conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> pip -> webencodings
pip -> webencodings
tensorflow[version='>=2.0.0'] -> tensorboard[version='>=2.0.0'] -> webencodings

Package libflang conflicts for:
scipy[version='>=1.5.2'] -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0']
scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2'] -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> libflang[version='>=5.0.0']

Package vs2010_runtime conflicts for:
six[version='>=1.15.0'] -> python -> vs2010_runtime
progressbar33[version='>=2.4'] -> python -> vs2010_runtime
tqdm[version='>=4.49.0'] -> python -> vs2010_runtime
pip -> python[version='>=3'] -> vs2010_runtime

Package python_abi conflicts for:
numpy=1.18.5 -> python_abi[version='3.6.*|3.8.*|3.7.*',build='*_cp37m|*_cp38|*_cp36m']
scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2'] -> python_abi[version='3.6.*|3.8.*|3.7.*',build='*_cp37m|*_cp38|*_cp36m']
scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2'] -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> python_abi=3.9[build=*_cp39]
joblib[version='>=0.16.0'] -> setuptools -> python_abi[version='3.6.*|3.7.*|3.9.*|3.8.*',build='*_cp38|*_cp39|*_cp37m|*_cp36m']
scipy[version='>=1.5.2'] -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0'] -> python_abi[version='3.6.*|3.8.*|3.9.*|3.7.*',build='*_cp37m|*_cp36m|*_cp38|*_cp39']
gensim[version='>=3.8.3'] -> numpy[version='>=1.18.4,<2.0a0'] -> python_abi=3.9[build=*_cp39]
numpy=1.18.5 -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0'] -> python_abi=3.9[build=*_cp39]
pip -> setuptools -> python_abi[version='2.7.*|3.6.*|3.7.*|3.9.*|3.8.*',build='*_cp27m|*_cp38|*_cp39|*_cp37m|*_cp36m']
gensim[version='>=3.8.3'] -> python_abi[version='3.6.*|3.7.*|3.8.*',build='*_cp38|*_cp37m|*_cp36m']

Package six conflicts for:
six[version='>=1.15.0']
scipy[version='>=1.5.2'] -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0'] -> six
numpy=1.18.5 -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0'] -> six
pip -> html5lib -> six[version='>=1.9']
tensorflow[version='>=2.0.0'] -> tensorboard[version='>=2.1.0'] -> six[version='>=1.10.0|>=1.12|>=1.12.0,<2.0a0']
gensim[version='>=3.8.3'] -> six[version='>=1.5.0']

Package lockfile conflicts for:
pip -> lockfile
python=3.8 -> pip -> lockfile

Package zlib conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> sqlite[version='>=3.33.0,<4.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
tensorflow[version='>=2.0.0'] -> tensorflow-base==2.1.0=gpu_py36h55f5790_0 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']

Package scipy conflicts for:
gensim[version='>=3.8.3'] -> scipy[version='>=0.18.1']
scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2'] -> scipy
scipy[version='>=1.5.2']

Package joblib conflicts for:
scikit-learn[version='>=0.23.2'] -> joblib[version='>=0.11']
joblib[version='>=0.16.0']

Package intel-openmp conflicts for:
scipy[version='>=1.5.2'] -> mkl[version='>=2019.4,<2021.0a0'] -> intel-openmp
numpy=1.18.5 -> mkl[version='>=2019.4,<2021.0a0'] -> intel-openmpThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0
  - feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0

Your installed version is: 11.0


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-build-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_build.py", line 474, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_build.py", line 463, in execute
    outputs = api.build(args.recipe, post=args.post, test_run_post=args.test_run_post,
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\api.py", line 186, in build
    return build_tree(
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py", line 3000, in build_tree
    packages_from_this = build(metadata, stats,
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py", line 1968, in build
    output_metas = expand_outputs([(m, need_source_download, need_reparse_in_env)])
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py", line 757, in expand_outputs
    for (output_dict, m) in deepcopy(_m).get_output_metadata_set(permit_unsatisfiable_variants=False):
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\metadata.py", line 2062, in get_output_metadata_set
    conda_packages = finalize_outputs_pass(ref_metadata, conda_packages, pass_no=0,
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\metadata.py", line 735, in finalize_outputs_pass
    fm = finalize_metadata(om, parent_metadata=parent_metadata,
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py", line 531, in finalize_metadata
    build_unsat, host_unsat = add_upstream_pins(m,
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py", line 406, in add_upstream_pins
    host_deps, host_unsat, extra_run_specs_from_host = _read_upstream_pin_files(m, 'host',
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py", line 371, in _read_upstream_pin_files
    deps, actions, unsat = get_env_dependencies(m, env, m.config.variant,
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\render.py", line 139, in get_env_dependencies
    actions = environ.get_install_actions(tmpdir, tuple(dependencies), env,
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\environ.py", line 789, in get_install_actions
    raise DependencyNeedsBuildingError(exc, subdir=subdir)
conda_build.exceptions.DependencyNeedsBuildingError: Unsatisfiable dependencies for platform win-64: {"python_abi[version='3.6.*|3.8.*|3.9.*|3.7.*',build='*_cp37m|*_cp36m|*_cp38|*_cp39']", "python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.8.*|3.7.*']", "certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']", 'm2w64-gcc-libs', "python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.5|3.8.*|3.7.*']", "numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0']", "numpy-base[version='1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.17.2.*|1.17.3.*|1.17.4.*|1.18.1.*|1.18.5.*|1.19.1|1.17.0|1.17.0',build='py37hc3f5095_0|py36h8128ebf_4|py27h2753ae9_4|py37hc3f5095_5|py36h4a99626_0|py27hfef472a_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py35h8128ebf_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_1|py27hb1d0314_1|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py38ha3acd2a_0|py36ha3acd2a_0|py37ha3acd2a_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py38hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py37hc3f5095_1|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py27hb1d0314_1|py36hc3f5095_1|py37hc3f5095_1|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_1|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py35h8128ebf_0|py37h4a99626_0|py35h4a99626_0|py36hc3f5095_5|py27hb1d0314_5|py38hc3f5095_4|py35h8128ebf_4|py37h8128ebf_4|py36hc3f5095_0']", "python_abi[version='3.6.*|3.8.*|3.7.*',build='*_cp37m|*_cp38|*_cp36m']", "python_abi[version='3.6.*|3.7.*|3.8.*',build='*_cp38|*_cp37m|*_cp36m']", 'scipy', "python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3|3.4.*']", "joblib[version='>=0.11']", "python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']", "numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.15.1,<2.0a0']", "libflang[version='>=5.0.0']", "numpy[version='>=1.12.0|>=1.16|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.16.1']", "scipy[version='>=0.18.1']", "python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|3.4.*']", "numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.15.1,<2.0a0']", "six[version='>=1.5.0']", "python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5|>=3.2|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']", "numpy-base[version='1.18.1.*|1.18.5.*|1.19.1',build='py38ha3acd2a_0|py36ha3acd2a_0|py37ha3acd2a_0']", "numpy[version='>=1.18.1,<2.0a0|>=1.18.4,<2.0a0']", "python[version='>=3.6']", 'webencodings', 'feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0', 'six', "python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.4.*|>=3.5|3.7.*|3.8.*']", 'setuptools', 'feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0', 'numpy-base=1.18.5', 'python_abi=3.9[build=*_cp39]', "numpy-base[version='>=1.0.14,<2.0a0|>=1.0.6,<2.0a0|>=1.0.2,<2.0a0|>=1.0.4,<2.0a0']", "python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']", "six[version='>=1.9']", "python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']", "python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']", 'requests', "requests[version='>=2.21.0,<3']", 'vs2010_runtime', 'lockfile', 'tzdata', "certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26|>=2017.4.17']", "setuptools[version='>=41.0.0|>=41.4']", "zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']", 'python', 'intel-openmp', "python_abi[version='3.6.*|3.7.*|3.9.*|3.8.*',build='*_cp38|*_cp39|*_cp37m|*_cp36m']", "openblas[version='>=0.2.20,<0.2.21.0a0|>=0.3.3,<0.3.4.0a0']", "python_abi[version='2.7.*|3.6.*|3.7.*|3.9.*|3.8.*',build='*_cp27m|*_cp38|*_cp39|*_cp37m|*_cp36m']", 'ca-certificates', "numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0']", "python[version='3.6.*|3.7.*']", "numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0']", "six[version='>=1.10.0|>=1.12|>=1.12.0,<2.0a0']", "openblas[version='0.3.5.*|0.3.6|>=0.3.6,<0.3.7.0a0',build=h828a276_2]"}
```

I am new to Conda. All I want is to successfully build the package using `conda-build`.
After searching documentation of `conda-build` and other questions on Internet, I got no solution for this "conflicts" problem. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: By default, conda is building for Python 3.8. It looks like some of the dependencies you specified are not available for that Python version. If you want to restrict the version of Python you support, you'll need to add that to `meta.yaml`

Comment: @darthbith Thanks it works! Previously I thought if I activated a environment with Python 3.6 via `conda activate xxx`, `conda-build` would build with Python 3.6 as well : (

Comment: @darthbith Btw, may I ask one more question? The error message stated that "Package requests conflicts" information using format like: `python=3.8 -> pip -> requests`. I am not super clear about how to understand this info...

Comment: @ICYPOLE those are dependency chains (a constraint of `python=3.8` depends on `pip` which depends on `requests`). Most of what is output is useless (not an actual conflict). If the `python=3.8` really is the issue, then there should be a chain in there somewhere that ends with `-> python[<versions>]` where the `<versions>` does not include 3.8. It looks like `tensorflow>=2.0.0` could be the issue. Maybe `tensorflow>=2.2.0` might enable the Python 3.8 build to work. Not sure.

Comment: @merv Thanks for your explanation: ) Very accurate and clear

Comment: @ICYPOLE `conda-build` is always installed in the `base` environment and uses that environment's Python version as the default. That's why activating the environment didn't help.